# Changing the color of particular words in Textareafield in Sencha Touch

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to change the font color of the misspelled words in a Textareafield in Sencha Touch2. I have the array of misspelled words.
This is the textareafield.

```
           {
                xtype:'textareafield',
                label:'Note',
                id:'txt',
                scroll:'vertical',

            },
```

MisspeltArr will have the wrongly spelt words.

```
                    var misspeltArr =[];
                    for(i = 0;i<txtArr.length;i++){
                        var spellCheck = dictionary.check(txtArr[i]);
                        console.log("spellCheck : "+spellCheck);
                        if(spellCheck == false){
                            misspeltArr.push(txtArr[i]);
                        }
                    }
```

Say i have typed the below text in the textareafield,

```
   Thisss is a mobile application screennn
```

Now in txt I have the text entered

```
  var txt = Ext.getCmp('txt').getValue();
```

I want to change the color or underline the wrong words - Thisss and screennn (words in the array) in the textareafield. I have achieved spell check and all I want to do is Highlighting the wrong words. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have to use something more advanced than  textarea. Something such as iframe may do the job

Comment: @Attila : Ok. If in case I'm using plain html   {html:'<textarea id="txt">sample</textarea>'},I can get the value : document.getElementById("txt").value;
I can get the index of the wrong spelled word
 foundIndex = txt.indexOf(sample); But how do I change the color of the sub string there. Can you pls help me with this.

Comment: @Mostafa : This is for a mobile app. How can i use iFrame to solve this prob? Please can u elaborate.